# Bootstrap 3.3 stacked nav bar content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a web page that needs vertical nav bar (stacked nav bar in Bootstrap 3), but the content seems a little bit tricky as all of them are shown below the whole bar.

Actually I wanna the panel placed in the left of the page and the content in the right, just as a vertical menu.

I've tried it with row-col (Bootstrap grid system), but the content seems to be float down when I click the lower tab.

This is my code I used with no grid system:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a href="#user1" data-toggle="tab">Panel1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#user2" data-toggle="tab">Panel2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#user3" data-toggle="tab">Panel3</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="user1">
                <p>This is panel1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade"  id="user2">
                <p>This is panel2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="user3">
                <p>This is panel3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the functionality you're looking for, you will have to use the grid system. Below is an example in a snippet. View it full screen after running the snippet for a better view of it.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a href="#user1" data-toggle="tab">Panel1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#user2" data-toggle="tab">Panel2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#user3" data-toggle="tab">Panel3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="user1">User 1 info</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="user2">User 2 info</div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="user3">User 3 info</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I mistakenly use the gird system before!

Answer (score 1):

It works with `col` classes. Did you mean something like [this?](http://www.bootply.com/vWSyNBScLq)